# How can my personal ISP connection return two public IP addresses?

Tags: router, ip, ipv4

I want to play a game (Wildstar) but each time I login, it gives me an “invalid login token” error. After looking into the issue, I found that it was caused by, according to Wildstar:

> WHAT DOES IT MEAN? This error is caused by some automatic "potential
>   hacker" detection software that is run on the authentication servers.
>   To wit: "Our authentication server detected a change in your IP
>   address, and denied you entry because of a potential 'man in the
>   middle' hacking attempt.
>
> WHY DOES THIS HAPPEN? When you try to connect to the game, it connects
>   first to the authentication server, and then the game servers. If the
>   system detects that connection coming from 2 different IP addresses,
>   it flags you as a potential hacker.
>
> WHAT SHOULD I DO? We've seen this problem happen on occasion to people
>   using Wi-Fi at their school, or routing through a proxy server. Our
>   best solution at this point is to go through a wired connection, or
>   find an access point with less traffic. Unfortunately this isn't
>   something that we can disable, since we don't want hackers to be able
>   to log in to other people's accounts and steal characters or items
>   that don't belong to them. This should be a rare issue, but if it does
>   happen to you, try to simplify your internet connection as much as
>   possible. Try a direct, wired connection, and make sure you're not
>   connecting through a proxy server.

And so, it seems the issue is having two IPs displayed? I’m trying to play at home, so no campus/school issue and I’m not using a proxy server. The only thing I can’t try is using a wired connection.

I’ve tried making my IP static, but that doesn't keep my router from giving me another IP address (even if I reserved my IP on the router’s configuration).

My IPs look like this:

IPv4: `192.168.x.x`

Public IP 1 (What’s my IP): `190.92.xx.xx`

IP from [whatismyipaddress.com](http://whatismyipaddress.com/) gives me: `190.211.xxx.xxx`

I [tried doing this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/) but it didn’t solve anything.

If it helps, my router is an [Arris WTM552](http://arris.force.com/consumers/ConsumerProductDetail?p=a0ha000000NJnxcAAD&c=Touchstone%20Modems%20and%20Gateways) with a Dynamic Connection Type and a DCHP server enabled. I’ve tried setting the connection to a static one and disabling the DCHP server, but it still won’t work.

Any help? The game’s support won’t help me with this. In fact, their response was a copy/paste of an article they already had for this; the one I posted above.

Comment: What is "Public Ip 1" and how did you ascertain that?

Comment: That's just the ip Google gave me when I typed "What's my Ip".

Comment: Is it possible that your ISP is giving you CGN (Carrier Grade NAT)? This is where a small number of real IP addresses are shared with a larger number of customers to conserve IP address space.

Answer (score 2):

From what you have mentioned, your PC has a private IP (192.X series) whereas your router is connected to an ISP (Internet Service Provider) which provides you a public IP (190.X).

Making your private IP 'static' will not solve the issue.

The ISP should give you a single IP for a given session. I use an ADSL connection and my public IP remains the same till I reboot my router. Talk to your ISP and verify this is also the case for you.

Comment: ISPs may decide to change the IP address, where your connections seem to come from for someone outside of the ISP (like your gameserver). They may also decide to route your different connections through different IP address, for load balancing. It is not very good practice, but unfortunately common. Talking to your ISP is the right way to obtain a solution.

Comment: I see... I was actually afraid that it would come down to that since my ISP isn't very flexible when it comes to requests. But anyways, thank you for your answers!